# finding gaps in schedule

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weekly schedule for an app I'm writing using PHP and MySQL. You can add appointments per day, for example:

```
Monday:   06:00 until 12:00
          12:00 until 14:00
Tuesday:  08:00 until 12:00
          12:00 until 18:00
etc
```

My (concatenated) schema/table is:

```
ID (int11)
eventName (String)
dtStart   (timestamp)
dtEnd     (timestamp)
```

This functionality is working right now, but for a special feature I'm working on I need to detect if there are any times in the week/day where there is no appointment scheduled ("free time") as this is undesirable (the goal is to have at least one thing scheduled for every minute of the week, but it is also possible for appointments/events to overlap). I'm using mySQL as the database with an appointment start date and end date as a mySQL timestamp.

At first I was thinking I could take the time each scheduled event would take (12:00 - 06:00 = 6 hours) and add them all up to see if totalHours - (24 * 7) = 0.

But firstly this doesn't detect where the gaps are and secondly since events can overlap it would be very unreliable.

Is there anyway to detect this in a reasonable way?

Comment: There is no way we can answer this from the information provided.

Comment: What additional information are you missing? Genuine question, I would like to know how to improve my question asking

Comment: Well, the table schema is a step in the right direction. Typically, I would suggest the following, simple, two-step course of action: 1. Pprovide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. Pprovide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

First... consider the granularity of your data... What's the smallest time for your data? Minutes? Seconds?. Be careful here: excessive granularity may kill your server... Once you got that, try and move away from mysql for this task.

The way I would go?. A small class php suited for the task:

```
class Data
{
private $begin;
private $end;

public function __construct($b, $e)
{
$this->begin=$b;
$this->end=$e;
}

public function overlaps_with(Data $d)
{
//Small logic here... The easiest way to assert that something overlaps is to check that it doesn't, then negate the results. Remember, check for self overlapping!!!. If $d and $this are the same you should react accordingly.
}

public function merge_with(Data $d)
{
//Set begin and end to the earliest and latest among $d and $this. 
}
};
```

Fetch all data for a given day and create Data instances with it, filling a container. Sort them by beginning time. Iterate through all of them and, for each one, merge_with if overlaps_with, disposing of the compared entry.

Once every item has been iterated you will ideally have only one entry left, that begins and ends when the limits on your application are. Do you have more than one entry?. Well, there's free time there, just iterate your container and compare each entry's end with the next begginning.

If you think about it, it's like laying the schedule on paper and colouring in a single tone every entry that is following or followed by another. What's left uncolured is free time.

Comment: FWIW, I think (My)SQL is a perfectly good tool for this kind of task.

Comment: Awesome answer, very informative. I'm going to try to work this out and report back!

Comment: No prob. Let us know if we can help. @Strawberry, yeah, SQL can be an awesome tool, quick and concise but well, IMHO it can also get ugly when huge nested queries and procedures are concerned. Honestly, I haven't thought of the SQL answer, there's just a certain plasticity to data structures and algorithms that can be very elegant and readable :).